# Statistic to find out association between ordinal data

Tags: intraclass-correlation

I have a 4x3 contigency table with ordinal data  for a research finding in tuberculosis, I analysed cytology patterns and afb patterns; cytological pattern $A,B,C,D$ (independent variable) and afb pattern 1,2,3 (dependent variable) and put a 4x3 table with number of cases in corresponding cell.

Which statistical test can I use to find out if pattern A is associated with afb pattern 1 and pattern C/D is associated with afb pattern 3? I cannot use chi square as one cell has no cases and two cells have < 5 cases

Comment: The chi-square approximation doesn't rely on the number of cases being some number, but on the expected values.

Answer (score 1):

You would use **Fisher’s exact test**.

> The Fisher's exact test is used when you want to conduct a chi-square
>   test, but one or more of your cells has an expected frequency of five
>   or less.  Remember that the chi-square test assumes that each cell has
>   an expected frequency of five or more, but the Fisher's exact test has
>   no such assumption and can be used regardless of how small the
>   expected frequency is.

Source: UCLA, What statistical analysis should I use? [link](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/whatstat/whatstat.htm#exact)